# Root mean square function (RMS) in the ODEs of a dynamical system

Tags: derivatives, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to obtain the differential equations of a dynamic system in which one of the blocks calculates the RMS of a signal. When arranging the ODEs I see that the differential version of the RMS formula is needed, if I'm not wrong. However I am finding difficulties deriving it from its usual form:

$x_{rms}(t)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int_{t-T}^t x(\tau)^2 d\tau}$

Do I really need to use the derivative, or a different approach is needed to incorporate the block into the equations of the system for its simulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't say something sensible about the use of the derivative, since I don't know the specifics of your system. However, it *is* possible to derive an ODE for $x_\text{rms}$.

Note that $x_\text{rms}$ is a function of $T$ only. Therefore, we can calculate its derivative to $T$: we obtain
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d} x_\text{rms}}{\text{d} T} &= \frac{1}{2 T^2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T x(t)^2 \text{d} t}}\left(-\int_0^T x(t)^2 \text{d} t + T \,x(T)^2\right) \\
&= \frac{- T^2 x_\text{rms}^2(T) + T\,x(T)^2}{2 T^2 x_\text{rms}(T)}\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}x_\text{rms}(T) + \frac{1}{2 T} \frac{x(T)^2}{x_\text{rms}(T)}.
\end{align}

**Addition:** Using the new expression for $x_\text{rms} $, we get
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} x_\text{rms}}{\text{d} t}(t) = \frac{x(t)^2 - x(t-T)^2}{2 T x_\text{rms}(t)}.
\end{equation}
This yields a *delay differential equation* in terms of $x$ and $x_\text{rms} $, which brings about its own issues in terms of solving. I strongly suggest you look into these aspects, using the term 'delay differential equation' as lead.

Comment: Even though your answer is interesting, I need its derivative with respect to time $t$, which is the dependent variable in a dynamical system - to get the evolution of the system as time passes. My last try is this: $\frac{dx_{rms}}{dt}=\frac{1}{2x_{rms}T}(x(t)^2-x(t-T)^2)$. This way the range is restricted, and it would be zero for a T-periodic signal $x(t)$, I believe. I'd need confirmation though...

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible, since $x_\text{rms}$ is a function of $T$ only. Of course, it has $x(t)$ as input, but as an *integral*. Therefore, $x_\text{rms}$ does not depend on $x$ at some point $t$, but on the *entire solution* $x(t)$, with $t$ ranging from 0 to $T$. I believe that you might be confused between the roles of $t$ and $T$. Ask yourself: would your question make more sense if $x_\text{rms}$ was defined as $x_\text{rms}(t) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t x(\tau)^2\,\text{d} \tau}$?

Comment: I understand what you mean, and while it might be true that it is not possible, I think that there might be an error from my part in the problem statement. It should actually be $x_{rms}(t)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int^t_{t-T}x(\tau)^2 d\tau}$. I don't think this is exactly the same as your last formula, or is it?

Comment: No, this new definition of $x_\text{rms} $ definitely changes things, you're right. Maybe you can modify your question, and I can try to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the confusion.